# How to programmatically get the names of apps that currently are in the recents stack of android?

Tags: android, android-recents

I need some code to get an object or an arraylist that contains all the names of those applications that **currently are in the recents stack of android**. Maybe android doesn't permit to do that (for security reasons) so even code which needs root permissions is ok for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Use `getRunningAppProcesses`, which will return a list of `RunningAppProcessInfo` objects that will give you some data about each running app. One of the pieces of information you can retrieve about the app is its `importance`, which can have a value `IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND` which indicates that the process is the currently active.

Some guide For you as well.

[`IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html?hl=vi#IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND)

[`RunningAppProcessInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html?hl=vi)

**Solution 2:**
I was also developing an application for locking the apps. It seems you need to ask user to provide this setting. I used this activity to check which app is in foreground but I Guess it can work according to you also.

```
Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS
```

On my mobile It's written

> Allow apps to **monitor** which other apps you use and how often,and
>   identify your service provider, language and other usage data.

`UsageStatsManager` has some useful methods that can satisfy your need.

i think you need to ask this from your user and if the user agrees. you can use gain access to the recent Apps.